# Pandas - Select maximum value for each instance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE': [-22.22, -22.43, -22.22, -22.43, -22.35, -22.35, -22.35, -22.21]})
df['Importance'] = df.groupby('LATITUDE').cumcount().add(1)
df
```

How can I generate another dataframe with only the maximum value of each instance?

Output Example:

```
LATITUDE | Importance
-22.22   | 2
-22.43   | 2
-22.35   | 3
-22.21   | 1
```

Comment: Seems like you're really after `df.groupby('LATITUDE', sort=False).size()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?  To be honest, I'm a little confused by your 'Importance' column.  Is this part of the dataset, or is this an attempt to solve your issue?  Either way, I've treated it as part of your dataset ...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE': [-22.22, -22.43, -22.22, -22.43, 
                                -22.35, -22.35, -22.35, -22.21]})
df['Importance'] = df.groupby('LATITUDE').cumcount().add(1)

# Return the LATITUDE and Importance with max Importance.
df2 = df.groupby('LATITUDE', as_index=False).agg({'Importance': max})
```

#### Before:

```
   LATITUDE  Importance
0    -22.22           1
1    -22.43           1
2    -22.22           2
3    -22.43           2
4    -22.35           1
5    -22.35           2
6    -22.35           3
7    -22.21           1
```

#### After:

```
   LATITUDE  Importance
0    -22.43           2
1    -22.35           3
2    -22.22           2
3    -22.21           1
```

Let me know if you're after something else ...

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.groupby('LATITUDE', as_index=False).max()
```